# Booking a bus in Japan to catch early morning flights at Narita airport

Tags: online-resources, japan, buses, bookings

The online booking website for [Access Narita](http://accessnarita.jp/en/home/) and [Keisei](http://www.keiseibus.co.jp/) both require my name in Japanese katakana. Is the name really required for verification or I can make up any name Japanese name?

Comment: Try Google Translate, English to Japanese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, your name in kana is not really required, it's just that the booking systems for both sites are 100% geared for Japanese people.  But instead of making something up, just punch your name into [Google Translate and let it do the work](https://translate.google.com/#en/ja/James%20Smith): James Smith → ジェームス·スミス.

That said, **I wouldn't bother booking at all**, the buses are virtually never full.  Just show up a little early if you're stressed out about missing your flight.